# Jersey2: Navigating from a Resource to an instance

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

I am attempting to answer this question: [What is the Jersey 2 replacement for ResourceContext.matchResource(URI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17284419/14731)

I've managed to navigate from a `ResourceModel` to a matching `Resource`, but it's not clear how to instantiate the corresponding user class.

Meaning, **given `org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.Resource` that maps to some user-defined class `CompaniesResource`, how do I get a `CompaniesResource` instance out of the `Resource`?**

The tricky part is that this needs to invoke subresource locators with values parsed from the URI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

Take a look at `createResource` found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/23620747/14731